# Overriding layout of existing/sample categories in magento

Tags: xml, magento

I have installed Magento with sample data. It has categories and products. I added one new category to default category. I followed some tutorial to change the left and right sidebars via XML below is my xml

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <layout>
    <catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <remove name="left.permanent.callout" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <remove name="left.newsletter" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <remove name="cart_sidebar" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
</layout>`

For my newly created category the above xml works fine ie remove the left sidebar items and also loads 2 column layout as I specified in the xml. But for the existing categories it is not working.
I also went to edit the existing category and in the design tab I changed every thing to default. Mean it is not using any overrides from there.
Can any one please tell me is there any other panel or xml where these categories pages are taking templates from.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would Just want to add that
1) Cache is turned off
2) when I edit the layout.xml file and add some non formated (non-xml) text then the execution is stopped and error message is shown. Which means that system reads the XML for both cases ie one for my newly created category and other for existing category for which I want to change the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing `catalog_category_layered` handle.

```
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <remove name="left.permanent.callout" />
        <remove name="left.newsletter" />
        <remove name="cart_sidebar" />
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Comment: I would like to add here that the existing catgegories are marked as anchor in display settings tab. Mean they will allow us filter list by attribute. Any category marked as anchor will be using the xml from the node catalog_category_layered.